# Tkinter canvas not showing image

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, python-imaging-library, tkinter-canvas

I can get tkinter to display the windows or the background image, does anyone have a suggestion of how to get both displayed at once (I want the objects to go onto the background image), my code is below:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk


root= Tk()
# Code to add widgets will go here...
root.title("MTGO Daily Decklists")
def test():
    print("things")

# pick a .gif image file you have in the working directory
# or give full path
image1 = PhotoImage(file="backgroundimage.gif")
w = Canvas(root, width=800, height=700,)
background = PhotoImage(file = "backgroundimage.gif")
w.create_image(500, 500, image=image1)
w.pack()
format_mtg= StringVar()
format_entry= ttk.Entry(w, width=25, textvariable=format_mtg)
format_entry_window = w.create_window(10, 10, anchor='n', window=format_entry)
format_entry.pack()
date= StringVar()
date_entry=ttk.Entry(root, width=25, textvariable=date)
date_entry_window = w.create_window(10, 10, anchor='n', window=date_entry)
date_entry.pack()
ttk.Label(w, text="input format here").pack()
ttk.Button(w, text="fetch", command=test).pack()
ttk.Label(w, text="input date here").pack()
sortby= StringVar()
sortby_entry= ttk.Entry()
sortby_entry.pack()
ttk.Label(w, text="input how you want the decklists to be sorted").pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I don't see any attempt at creating a canvas image out of the background image.

Comment: oops, i changed
    w.create_image(500, 500, image=image1)
to
    w.create_image(500, 500, image=background)
but it still has the same issue

Comment: When you changed it to `image=background`, did you add a line to create the canvas image for `image1`, or are you only ever creating one image?

Comment: just one image, i read that you needed to keep a reference to the image somewhere so it wasn't removed when tkinter closes

Comment: If you wanted to print two objects, `a` and `b`, would you try `print(a)`, see that it prints only `a`, change it to `print(b)`, see that it only prints `b`, and then theorize that it's impossible to print two things? Or would you have a line with `print(a)` and then _another line_ with `print(b)`?

Comment: to put widget on Canvas use only `create_window(w, ...)` - you don't need `.pack()`. To put outside Canvas use `pack()` and `root` as parent, not `w`. Now you mix both method and get mess.

Answer (score 2):

You are placing the center of the image at 500x500. However, after the program starts your window is only about 300x200. Your image is likely there, but off of the visible portion of the screen.

Even though you set the size of the canvas to 800x700, you are packing widgets inside the canvas. This causes the canvas to shrink to fit its contents. Compounding that, you don't use the `expand` or `fill` options when packing the canvas so the end result is that the interior of the GUI shrinks down to the minimum size.

note: if you are using `create_window` to add a window to a canvas, you should *not* also call `grid` or `pack` on that window. You need to call either `create_window` or `pack`, but not both. Whichever one you call last is the one that has any effect.

There are many solutions, the choice of which depends on what your ultimate goal is. If you want the canvas to be forced to a height of 800x700 regardless of the window size or the size of its contents, you can turn geometry propagation off inside the canvas. For example:

```
w.pack_propagate(False)
```

You could also pack the canvas to fill the space given to it and then anchor the background image to the upper-left corner. For example:

```
w.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
w.create_image(0, 0, image=image1, anchor="nw")
```

You could also stop using a canvas, and put the background image in a label. You can then use `place` to center the label in the main window. For example:

```
background_label = Label(root, image=image1)
background_label.place(relx=.5, rely=.5)
```